# NameError: global name 'row' is not defined (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark

I 've problem with a function in pyspark (I'm practicing as starter).
I've this function:

```
%pyspark
#Fuction to define and take in all the variables.
def myfunc(line):
    l1=line.split(",")
    return row(Id=l1[0],MSSubClass=l1[1],MSZoning=l1[2],LotFrontage=str(l1[3]),
               LotArea=str(l1[4]),Street=l1[5],Alley=l1[6],
               LotShape=l1[7],LandContour=l1[8],Utilities=l1[9],LotConfig=l1[10],
               LandSlope=l1[11],Neighborhood=l1[12],Condition1=l1[13],Condition2=l1[14],BldgType=l1[15],
               HouseStyle=l1[16],OverallQual=l1[17],OverallCond=l1[18],YearBuilt=l1[19],YearRemodAdd=l1[20],
               RoofStyle=l1[21],RoofMatl=l1[22],Exterior1st=l1[23],Exterior2nd=l1[24],MasVnrType=l1[25],
               MasVnrArea=l1[26],ExterQual=l1[27],ExterCond=l1[28],Foundation=l1[29],BsmtQual=l1[30],
               BsmtCond=l1[31],BsmtExposure=l1[32],BsmtFinType1=l1[33],BsmtFinSF1=str(l1[34]),BsmtFinType2=l1[35],
               BsmtFinSF2=str(l1[36]),BsmtUnfSF=str(l1[37]),TotalBsmtSF=str(l1[38]),Heating=l1[39],HeatingQC=l1[40],
               CentralAir=l1[41],Electrical=l1[42],firstFlrSF=str(l1[43]),secondFlrSF=str(l1[44]),LowQualFinSF=l1[45],
               GrLivArea=str(l1[46]),BsmtFullBath=str(l1[47]),BsmtHalfBath=str(l1[48]),FullBath=str(l1[49]),
               HalfBath=str(l1[50]),BedroomAbvGr=str(l1[51]),KitchenAbvGr=str(l1[52]),KitchenQual=l1[53],
               TotRmsAbvGrd=str(l1[54]),Functional=l1[55],Fireplaces=str(l1[56]),
               FireplaceQu=l1[57],GarageType=l1[58],GarageYrBlt=l1[59],GarageFinish=l1[60],
               GarageCars=str(l1[61]),GarageArea=str(l1[62]),GarageQual=l1[63],GarageCond=l1[64],PavedDrive=l1[65],
               WoodDeckSF=str(l1[66]),OpenPorchSF=str(l1[67]),EnclosedPorch=str(l1[68]),threeSsnPorch=str(l1[69]),
               ScreenPorch=str(l1[70]),PoolArea=str(l1[71]),PoolQC=l1[72],Fence=l1[73],MiscFeature=l1[74],
               MiscVal=str(l1[75]),MoSold=l1[76],YrSold=l1[77],SaleType=l1[78],SaleCondition=l1[79],SalePrice=str(l1[80]))


res = rdddata.map(myfunc)
temp=spark.createDataFrame(res)
temp.dtypes
```

I got this error `NameError: global name 'row' is not defined (pyspark)` when I run `temp=spark.createDataFrame(res)`.

I initialize row to empty string then I got the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Could Anyone help me to understand. The tutorials  I follow  did the same thing.

Comment: `Row` is capitalized & dont forget your imports `from pyspark.sql import Row`

Comment: thanks I did inported the Row, I did it, but I still have the second error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` I have may be to errase the memory. I 'm using zapplin in aws.

Comment: Don't initialize row to empty string, just create a `Row` instance and return it.

Comment: How can I do it, pleas? `Row = Row()`
I used `from pyspark.sql import Row as Rows` but not working.

Comment: Then use `Rows` instead of `Row`. `Row = Rows()`. Is this also failing?

Comment: Also - you can consider different way of initializing pyspark dataframe from rdd: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections